# Uniform convergence equivalent to Cauchy criterion

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces

The equivalence of uniform convergence of a series of functions on a metric space and the Cauchy-criterion for this series of functions is, at least what I thought, only given if the metric space is complete. But then I read Rudin - Principles of Mathematical Analysis 3.ed. p.147,148 and where this equivalence is stated nowhere it is mentioned that the metric space in which the subset is embedded has to be complete. I am kind of shocked/confused now. Is the stated equivalence true?

Comment: "In the present chapter we confine our attention to complex-valued functions."

Comment: It is indeed stated at the very beginning of the chapter, stupid me...